# How to display the dates without DUPLICATE and ORDER by MAX DATE

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-5.5, table, greatest-n-per-group

I just want to ask that how can I display the null values along with the MAX date.

```
SELECT 
  MEMB.MEMB_N,
  MEMB.LAST_M,
  PrintDate
FROM
  MEMB 
  INNER JOIN tblPrint 
    ON MEMB.MEMB_N = tblPrint.MEMB_N 
ORDER BY tblPrint.`PrintDate` DESC
```

My desired output will look like this but without duplicates.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **yet** another installment of the MySQL `sql_mode = only_full_group_by` saga.

`<rant>`
The problem is that MySQL's default (till 8) will return results which, depending on the order of the records being `INSERT`ed into the table (and/or `PRIMARY KEY` ordering), will vary and be correct or wrong **DEPENDING**. This is absolutely the **worst** sort of difficult to reproduce error that is so typical of MySQL.
`<\rant>`

However, it is good to see that MySQL's default behaviour is now the correct one (more than 25 years after PostgreSQL, FirebirdSQL, and the major vendors (Oracle, SQL Server &c...)!!).

What you need to do is the following:

-- create the tables - the fiddle (for MySQL version 8 is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d8a2815fe87f361f4f93023f36adb1e0))

```
CREATE TABLE memb 
(
  last_m VARCHAR (30),
  CONSTRAINT memb_pk PRIMARY KEY (last_m)
);
```

-- and

```
CREATE TABLE tblprint
(
  last_m VARCHAR (30),
  printdate DATETIME NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT tp_pk PRIMARY KEY (last_m, printdate),
  CONSTRAINT tp_memb_fk FOREIGN KEY (last_m) REFERENCES memb (last_m)
);
```

-- see end of this answer for populating these tables with data

I added more records and deliberately inserted them in an order which was not that of the dates either `ASCENDING` or `DESCENDING` - see discussion below.

The **correct** answer is

```
SELECT 
  m.last_m,
  MAX(tp.printdate) AS "p_date"
  -- COALESCE(MAX(tp.printdate), '"NULL"') AS "for_display" -- optional, just for show!
FROM
  tblprint tp
RIGHT JOIN memb m
  ON tp.last_m = m.last_m
GROUP BY last_m
ORDER BY last_m, p_date;
```

Strictly speaking, the `RIGHT JOIN` should be a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`.

Result:

```
last_m  p_date
ANDRES, JOSE    2024-07-29 13:33:24
LORISA, MARIA   2021-07-29 13:37:44
SENINA, JUSTINA 
TAN, LOLITA
```

which is the correct result, no matter what the record insertion order is.

Now, there is an alternative fiddle for version 5.6 (available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=41c7763d07dcbda1b2316a1dad8e4e63)) which is the closest to 5.5 which you are using. A dbfiddle.com version for 5.5 is available [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x161URhd41xXESjHHYq65m/1) - it appears to take the first date **arbitrarily** by `PRIMARY KEY` order - so it selects the smallest.

As you will be able to see - the defauts of MySQL, the 5.6 version, are much more permissive than 8. You **can** see that `sql_mode = only_full_group_by` for version 8. You can set this (**HIGHLY RECOMMENDED**) for [version 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by). I would also **strongly** recommend that you upgrade to version 8 - it's been around a while now.

You will also find that if you experiment with the record insertion order, you can get different results in 5.6 - for example, if by coincidence, the data is inserted in reverse date order by last_m into the `tblprinter` table, you will be able to get the "correct" results from [@HiteshRathi 's  query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/244096/34007) - of course this is **very very dangerous**!

I recommend that you "play around" with the various queries in the fiddles and see what happens - record insertion order and `PRIMARY KEY` order are factors to look at. Make sure your queries don't return different results with differing record insertion orders and/or `PRIMARY KEY` order.

-------------------- Data for the tables ---------------------------

```
INSERT INTO memb VALUES ('ANDRES, JOSE');
INSERT INTO memb VALUES ('LORISA, MARIA');
INSERT INTO memb VALUES ('SENINA, JUSTINA');
INSERT INTO memb VALUES ('TAN, LOLITA');

INSERT INTO tblprint VALUES ('ANDRES, JOSE', '2019-07-29 13:39:44');
INSERT INTO tblprint VALUES ('ANDRES, JOSE', '2001-09-01 23:33:41');
INSERT INTO tblprint VALUES ('ANDRES, JOSE', '2002-07-29 13:33:42');
INSERT INTO tblprint VALUES ('ANDRES, JOSE', '2003-07-29 13:33:43');
INSERT INTO tblprint VALUES ('ANDRES, JOSE', '2024-07-29 13:33:24');
INSERT INTO tblprint VALUES ('ANDRES, JOSE', '2020-07-29 20:20:20');

INSERT INTO tblprint VALUES ('LORISA, MARIA', '2014-07-29 13:34:44');
INSERT INTO tblprint VALUES ('LORISA, MARIA', '2007-07-29 13:31:44');
INSERT INTO tblprint VALUES ('LORISA, MARIA', '2008-07-29 13:32:44');
INSERT INTO tblprint VALUES ('LORISA, MARIA', '2009-07-29 13:33:44');
INSERT INTO tblprint VALUES ('LORISA, MARIA', '2018-07-29 13:35:44');
INSERT INTO tblprint VALUES ('LORISA, MARIA', '2021-07-29 13:37:44');
INSERT INTO tblprint VALUES ('LORISA, MARIA', '2020-07-29 13:36:44');
```

Comment: Hi! It worked haha. I learned so much from this answer, you explained all the query you gave!!! I really loved that you gave so many examples and thorough explanation for each version.  Now, I'm just absorbing all the information one by one :) God bless you Sir

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct MEMB.LAST_M LAST_M ,PrintDate as PrintDate 
FROM MEMB  
LEFT JOIN  tblPrint ON MEMB.MEMB_N = tblPrint.MEMB_N  
group by    
        MEMB.LAST_M ORDER BY PrintDate DESC;
```

Comment: And how do you know which record you're going to get for `ANDRES, JOSE`?

Comment: Hey @verace , well, my post is dangorus in the case ,if "tblprint" having multiple records for "printdate" for one member. i posted the answer with <max> function and <group by> clause only but later on i edited with by thinking members having same print date. well, nice explanation by you and hope question must be better explained! :)